# Django migrations not persisting

Tags: django, python-3.x, docker

My django app is containerized along side postgresql. The problem is that migrations do not seem to be persisting in the directory. Whenever I run `docker exec -it <container_id> python manage.py makemigrations forum`, the same migrations are detected. If I spin down the stack and spin it back up the and run makemigrations again, I see the same migrations detected. Changes to the fields, adding models, deleting models, none ever get detected. These migrations that do appear seem to be getting written to the database, as when I try to migrate, I get an error that there are existing fields already. But if I look at my migrations folder, only the **init**.py folder is present. All the migrate commands add no changes to the migrations folder.

I also tried unregistered the post model from the admin and spinning up the stack, yet I still see it present in the admin. Same things with changes to the templates. No change I make sticks from inside docker seems to stick.

*Note this problem started after I switched to wsl 2 and enabled it in docker desktop (windows)

**Update migrations can be made from bash of docker container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. My docker-stack.yml file was pointed to a directory that did not exist in the dockerfile.